How to implement collections in Redis as it works in MongoDB?
We use Redis DB for storing sessions. We change data format of sessions and need to migrate them by a little. As we want to save key format (session id), so the idea was to create a new collection (as in MongoDB) and put new sessions there. But I haven't found anything similar.
Also open for any best practices for situations like this.
